# About Adobe Air

Tags: php, javascript, air

I am quite new to Air and I know that it is for creating desktop apps using AS3. So my question is if I create air desktop app is it possbile to start it trough web application i.e using js or php?

Anyone idea?

Comment: Do you mean start the app on the users desktop when they navigate to a particular page?

Comment: yes for example when I press a link, the Air app opens. Can I send variables from js/php to the app?

Comment: I think the best you can do is associate the app with a file extension (one you make up) and then download a file with that extension. Your browser should offer to open the associated app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe AIR is a runtime environment like Java Virtual Machine. So to run any Adobe AIR application user must install AIR - Adobe Integrated Runtime - first. User can't just run an AIR app by clicking a link, instead he has to download it, install AIR if he has not installed, then install the downloaded application. You can use the same Actionscript codebase to build both Web application that runs in browser and Desktop application that runs on AIR environment in any OS.

Answer (score 1):

It is.  What I think you want is adobe's 'install badge' package, which is meant specifically for having a link in your website that:

if app is not installed, install it (and air if not installed)
if app is installed, launch the app on click

read the details here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_badge_install.html

Answer (score 0):

Adobe AIR is both a runtime and you can deploy directly without the runtime now with Captive Runtime(available for Android, Windows, natively with iOS). AIR apps do not run in the browser and therefore you cannot interact with it using js or php except u want to make service calls to the server. If you need a an app running in browser you would need to deploy the same code as a web project in flash builder with minimal effort.